# Pairing acquire / release operations between user and kernel space

Tags: c, linux-kernel, memory-barriers, memory-model, stdatomic

I am trying to ensure proper synchronization over a piece of memory shared between a user thread and another thread running in kernel mode on Linux.

Does it make sense to pair a C11's `atomic_store_explicit(memory_order_release)` from user space with an `smp_load_acquire()` from within the kernel and respectively an `atomic_load_explicit(memory_order_acquire)` with an `smp_store_release()`?

Comment: It's definitely fine on x86.  I'd guess probably on other ISAs where barriers are needed; there's usually only one obviously good choice of [C11 -> asm mapping for atomics](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html) even when barriers are required, so I'd expect that Linux is compatible with what compilers do.

Comment: The normal problem with this kind of thing is that the kernel doesn't know when that kernel thread should check if the value was changed; leading to a whole CPU being wasted by constant polling and/or the risk of data being missed (due to data changing multiple times while receiver isn't checking often enough). This is why most forms of "inter-process" communication (e.g. reading from a pipe) have built-in "tell scheduler to block this thread until data arrives in buffer" capabilities. If your use case is immune to this problem, then it's also immune to problems caused by "no barriers at all".

Comment: @Brendan I am indeed doing polling from a kernel thread that is pinned to a certain CPU core that is more or less dedicated to doing exactly that. Data cannot be missed because user threads produce something and don't touch it only until the kernel has consumed it. Disclosure: it's not mainline linux but a para-virtualized variant.

Comment: @Brendan I just want to make sure that the kernel doesn't see incomplete entries

Comment: @ilstam: Yeah, that sounds like "atomic store with no barrier" and "atomic read with no barrier" to me. ;-)

Comment: @Brendan I am not sure I understand what you mean. Do you mean to use `atomic_read`()/`atomic_set`() and no barriers? Or do you mean that the ordering guarantees offered by `smp_load_acquire()` and `smp_store_release()` are enough and no standalone memory barriers are required?

Comment: @ilstam: Yes, `atomic_read()` and `atomic_set()` without barriers. Any barriers (e.g. the barriers built into `smp_load_acquire()` and `smp_store_release()`) just make it slower with no benefit (because there's no difference between "polling slightly earlier than the write" and "polling slightly after the write and getting an older value this time" for your case).

Comment: @ilstam: Note that you may want more on some architectures for reasons that don't have anything to do with correctness (e.g. a `PAUSE` instruction on 80x86 in your polling loop, so that constant polling on one logical processor in a core causes less performance degradation for code running on the other logical processor/s sharing that core)

Comment: @Brendan I do need ordering guarantees because the kernel communicates the result back to the userspace via the same shared memory. So the kernel is going to update `result` and `status` for an entry, but of course I need to make sure that the result becomes globally visible before the `status` becomes "DONE". The entries are recycled once the userspace notices the kernel is done processing something. I guess `atomic_read()` and `atomic_set()` give me 0 ordering guarantees? Then I believe I cannot use them.

Comment: @ilstam: Ok; so user-space writes `value` with no barriers; then kernel eventually reads `value` with no barriers; then kernel writes `result` and `status` either in a specific order (requiring barriers) or atomically at the same time (requiring no barriers) by merging somehow (e.g. two 32-bit values combined into a single 64-bit value that is written and read atomically)?

Comment: @Brendan There is a struct with more fields, not just those 2. The userspace is going to update all of them and at the end update the status last from FREE/DONE to SUBMITTED. When the kernel finds out the status has changed, it's going to read all those values. So I am pretty sure there is a need for a store barrier in user-space and a load barrier in kernel space. I think the merging you suggest would work if there was a portable way to atomically write 64-bytes at once in all architectures, but I guess there isn't? :P

Comment: @ilstam: In that case, yes - user-space writes everything except `status`, then has a write barrier, then does an atomic write of  `status`; kernel sees write to `status` (via. polling with atomic read), then has read barrier, then reads the rest of the data. Same with roles reversed for passing results from kernel back to user-space. "All architectures" includes tiny 8-bit CPUs that don't support 32-bit either - you'd need to check whichever architectures you actually care about (e.g. 32-bit 80x86 CPUs, excluding 80386 and 80486, do support 64-bit atomic writes via. `CMPXCHG8B` instruction).

Comment: @Brendan So, as I ask in my original question, I would prefer to use acquire/release operations instead of standalone memory barriers, since acquire/release semantics can be a bit less strict. I wanted to see if others think it would be correct as well. Peter already said that he thinks it's fine.

Comment: @ilstam: As far as I can tell (at least on 80x86) the `smp_load_acquire()` and `smp_store_release()` macros in Linux are fundamentally broken and extremely dangerous, and will do nothing for your use case. Their "barrier" (same for both) is nothing more than a compiler barrier that will have no effect on the CPU's read ordering or write ordering (e.g. store forwarding) whatsoever.

Comment: @Brendan I find it very hard to believe that they are fundamentally broken. On x86 they produce nothing because x86 has a strong enough memory model and a compiler barrier is sufficient in that case. On ARM for example I see that they produce the proper stlr/ldar instructions.

Comment: @ilstam: For your use case, no. On 80x86 reads happen out of order; so CPU can read other data values before they have been written, then read `status` after it was written. You need a fence (`mfence` after the read of `status`) to prevent that. For writes it's a different problem - when the CPU writes to `status` the value can be forwarded to a later read of `status` by the same CPU, so the CPU may ignore writes done by other CPUs. You need a fence to prevent that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it definitely has a sense to pair C11 atomic `memory_order_release` and `memory_order_acquire` in user space with corresponded `smp_load_acquire` and `smp_store_release` in the kernel space when access the memory shared between kernel and user (e.g. via `mmap()`).

Acquire/release semantic provides similar guarantees both in C11 and Linux kernel and it would be very strange to find their implementation in machine instructions *incompatible*.

While C11 allows atomic instructions for "non-atomic" (too large) types, which could be implemented via locks, the Linux kernel bans usage of `smp_load_acquire` and `smp_load_release` for "non-atomic" types. So there is no risk to have C11 atomics implemented via user-space locks, which, of course, doesn't affect on the kernel.

Comment: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html documents the C11 -> asm mappings, in case anyone wants to compare with the Linux kernel definitions.  Agreed there's not much room for making different choices in which barriers go where for acq or rel.